# tried to access method java.lang.Object.clone()Ljava/lang/Object; from class ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.Utils

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am trying to generate Dynamic jasper reports from hibernate using the tutorial mentioned below

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2011/02/spring-3-dynamicjasper-hibernate.html

getting this error in download service class....

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method java.lang.Object.clone()Ljava/lang  /Object; from class ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.Utils
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.util.Utils.cloneStyle(Utils.java:111)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.layout.AbstractLayoutManager.generateTextFieldFromColumn(AbstractLayoutManager.java:711)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.layout.AbstractLayoutManager.transformDetailBand(AbstractLayoutManager.java:355)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.layout.AbstractLayoutManager.applyLayout(AbstractLayoutManager.java:143)
at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(DynamicJasperHelper.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
```

Any help about this...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahhh, resolved issue by upgrading jasper library from 2.4 to 3.7.6 ...